# Missing required parameters for route bus.edit

Tags: laravel

I got an error when I access menu, that show

> Missing required parameters for [Route: bus.edit] [URI: bus/{bu}/edit]

.

Code for view from button

```
<a href="{{ route('bus.edit',  ['bus' => $row["bus_id"]]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">
```

Routes

```
Route::resource('bus', 'BusController')->middleware('auth');
```

For controller

```
public function index()
{
    $data['title'] = "Buses";
    $data['menu'] = 1;
    $buses = DB::table('buses')
                    ->join('brands', 'buses.brand_id', '=', 'brands.brand_id')
                    ->get()->toArray();
    $data['buses'] = json_decode(json_encode($buses), true);
    $data['no'] = 1;
    return view('bus.index', $data);
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $data['title'] = "Edit Bus";
    $data['menu'] = 1;
    $data['bus'] = Bus::find($id);
    $data['brands'] = Brand::all();
    return view('bus.edit', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the system for plural/singular is broken for this word, `bus`, in 8.x you can specifically tell the resource what the route parameter should be named:

```
Route::resource('bus', 'BusController')
    ->parameters(['bus' => 'bus'])
    ->middleware('auth');
```

This would make the route parameter `bus` instead of `bu`. Then the call to the `route` helper you currently have would work.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you need to pass a single parameter called `{bu}`,
So  change it to :

```
{{ route('bus.edit',  ['bu' => $row["bus_id"]]) }}
```

Or,

```
{{ route('bus.edit',  $row["bus_id"]) }}
```

Comment: In case the `bu` doesn't make sense it seems that [the convention](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers) is to use the plural of your resource so it must have assumed `bus` is plural so `bu` would be it's singular form. Not sure what it would do if you used `buses` (maybe my comment is unnecessary but I find this situation amusing)

Comment: @apokryfos yea seems they broke the pluralizer/singularizer with that word, used to work fine in 5.5 at the least but in 8.x `Str::singular('bus')` is returning `bu` instead of `bus` ... fun times

Comment: @lagbox may be they found any word name singular is `bu` which plural is `bus`.

Comment: @sta who knows, it knows the plural of `bus` is `buses` ... i will have to open a PR with the pluralizer laravel uses from an outside source

Comment: @lagbox @apokryfos I tested on 5.8 , `Str::singular('bus');` but it gives me output `bu`